# .NET Regex find all SQL INSERT and Update with GETDATE

Tags: c#, sql, .net, regex

My company is moving our SQL databases to the cloud (Azure and AWS depending on client/region) so SQL server local datetime is no longer meaningful and we want to use UTC datetime instead. I need to identify all database objects (mostly Stored Procedures and functions) that are using `GETDATE()`. I have to automate this process because each database contains thousands of objects and we have many databases to migrate. Initially we are only applying this change to `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` columns present on most tables for auditing purposes.

Step by step:

1. (done) Identify all tables containing CreatedDate and ModifiedDate columns
2. (done) Identify all SQL objects that reference tables found in step 1
3. Regex each reference to see if it is updating or inserting into the table with `GETDATE()`

Step 3 is where I am stuck. The `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are inconsistently formatted for each database because the systems have been developed over a couple decades by many developers. I have a regex that is partially working but is failing to identify some multiline statements.

I am beginner-level with Regex so to make this easier on myself I broke the Regex into multiple steps. I am using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` in .NET for all operations.

The first step is to identify if the reference contains an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. This regex is working well and matches all examples in my test input.

```
(insert\s*into|update)\s*(MySchema.MyTable|MySchema.\[MyTable\]|\[MySchema].MyTable|\[MySchema\].\[MyTable\])
```

The second step is to check if the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement is using `GETDATE()`. My Regex is partially working but fails to identify multiline statements. What am I doing wrong here?

```
values\s*\((\s|.*)getdate()(\s|.*)\)|SET\s*.*=\s*getdate\(\)
```

The second problem I have is combining these two regex statements into one separated with `\s*.*`. Combining the two statements breaks some functionality that was previously working for each regex statement independently.

```
(insert\s*into|update)\s*(MySchema.MyTable|MySchema.\[MyTable\]|\[MySchema].MyTable|\[MySchema\].\[MyTable\])\s*.*values\s*\((\s|.*)getdate()(\s|.*)\)|SET\s*.*=\s*getdate\(\)
```

My sample input to reproduce results:

```
INSERT INTO [MySchema].[MyTable] (ID, ObjectValue, ObjectData, Col4, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LastModified, LastModifiedBy) VALUES (3, 'Hello', 'World', 12.32, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy)

INSERT INTO MySchema.MyTable (ID, ObjectValue, ObjectData, Col4, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LastModified, LastModifiedBy)
    VALUES (3, 'Hello', 'World', 12.32, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy)
    
INSERT INTO
    MySchema.MyTable
        (ID, ObjectValue, ObjectData, Col4, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LastModified, LastModifiedBy)
    VALUES
        (3, 'Hello', 'World', 12.32, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy)
        
INSERT INTO MySchema.[MyTable] (ID, 
    ObjectValue, 
    ObjectData, 
    Col4, 
    CreatedDate, 
    CreatedBy, 
    LastModified, 
    LastModifiedBy)
VALUES  (3, 'Hello', 'World', 12.32, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy)

INSERT INTO [MySchema].MyTable (ID , ObjectValue, ObjectData, Col4, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LastModified, LastModifiedBy)
VALUES (
    3, 
    'Hello', 
    'World', 
    12.32, 
    GETDATE(), 
    @CreatedBy, 
    GETDATE(), 
    @CreatedBy
)

UPDATE [MySchema].[MyTable] SET ID = 3, ObjectValue = 'Hello', ObjectData = 'World', Col4 = 12.32, LastModified = GETDATE(), LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy

UPDATE MySchema.MyTable
SET ID = 3, ObjectValue = 'Hello', ObjectData = 'World', Col4 = 12.32, LastModified = GETDATE(), LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy

UPDATE
    MySchema.MyTable
SET
    ID = 3, 
    ObjectValue = 'Hello', 
    ObjectData = 'World', 
    Col4 = 12.32, 
    LastModified = GETDATE(), 
    LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy
    
UPDATE MySchema.[MyTable] SET ID = 3, ObjectValue = 'Hello', ObjectData = 'World', 
Col4 = 12.32, LastModified = GETDATE(), LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy

UPDATE [MySchema].MyTable
    SET ID = 3, ObjectValue = 'Hello', ObjectData = 'World', Col4 = 12.32, LastModified = GETDATE(), LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy
```

Comment: so your file only consists insert and update statement ? no more statement ?

Comment: Why so complex? Why not "find insensitive 'getdate'", "replace 'GetUtcDate'"?

Comment: @CaiusJard initially we are only applying this change to Created/Modified column dates so find and replace every instance of `GETDATE()` is not appropriate. I will update my OP to include this detail.

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman The SQL sample I posted was for testing my regex only and to allow someone to reproduce my results. The scripts found in the database a large with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` only forming a small part of them.

Comment: @mr.coffee Do you want to applly your regex over a file where  all these statements belong ? or you have list of string consisting separate string for each statement.  Regex solution will be different for each case

Comment: *fails to identify multiline statements* - have you set [SingleLine mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#single-line-mode), so that `.` matches \n?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have not tried that. I will give it a go, thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, post up your actual c# so we can see. Remember that RegexOptions is a flags, so if you already set IgnoreCase, it's `IgnoreCase|SingleLine`

Comment: @Rizwan I apply the regex to each SQL object e.g. Stored Procedure or Function.

Answer (score 1):

> SQL server local datetime is no longer meaningful and we want to use UTC datetime instead

Azure uses UTC; put your database on Azure and GetDate() will start returning UTC times.

There are no code changes needed; on Azure both GetDate() and GetUtcDate() return the UTC time

Happy to keep working through your mission to switch over to using GetUtcDate, but I did want to point out it's not strictly necessary..

Comment: I did not know Azure uses UTC for `GETDATE()`. We will potentially still have some onprem deployments for a few clients who insist. We would like to move everything to UTC eventually for consistency. Thank you!